# Aggregate constexpr default contructor error with partial NSDMI

Tags: c++, initialization, aggregate, constexpr, default-constructor

I have a simple structure below which is used in constant expressions with [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) syntax. Now, I would like to make `test::c` optional thanks to [NSDMI](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) but this triggers an error for the default constructor in constant expression context with gcc and clang.

I don't understand why implicit default constructor default-initializes all members in first case but not with NSDMI.
There is no error if I set default value to all members but this is not what I want.
Moreover, I cannot declare a default constructor because the structure will no longer be an aggregate.

1. How the default contructor is implicitly generated in both case ? Is there a standard rule ?
2. Is there a way to fix the error and conserve the warning *[-Wmissing-field-initializers]* ?

```cpp
#include "debug.h"

struct test {
    //OK
    /* int a, b, c; */
    /* int a=0, b=0, c=3; */
    //ERROR
    int a, b, c=3;
};

int main(){
    const test val1 = test();     //{0,0,3}
    constexpr test val2 = test(); //error: call to non-'constexpr' function 'test::test()'
    constexpr test val3 = {};     //{0,0,3}
    constexpr test val4 = {1};    //warning: missing initializer for member 'test::b'
    constexpr test val5 = {1,2};  //{1,2,3}
}
```

Output :

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:13:32: error: call to non-'constexpr' function 'test::test()'
     constexpr test val2 = test();
                                ^
test.cpp:3:8: note: 'test::test()' is not usable as a 'constexpr' function because:
 struct test {
        ^~~~
test.cpp:8:9: note: defaulted default constructor does not initialize 'int test::a'
     int a, b, c=3;
         ^
test.cpp:8:12: note: defaulted default constructor does not initialize 'int test::b'
     int a, b, c=3;
            ^
test.cpp:15:29: warning: missing initializer for member 'test::b' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
     constexpr test val4 = {1};
                             ^
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's wrong with `int a{}, b{}, c = 3;`?

Comment: @L.F. it makes *a* and *b* optional, only *c* should be.

Comment: Then why should `test()` compile?

Comment: Because every types should be default constructible, even enums are for example.

Comment: No, not every type has to be default constructible.  In this case, you don’t want the a and b to be omitted, so it doesn’t make much sense to make test default constructible.  Enums are just an example of default constructible type; A satisfies P doesn’t mean everything should satisfy P.

Comment: But in this example, ```test``` must be and is default constructible without constant expression context, but I need also to default initialize it in constexpr. The problem is the inconsistency of behavior with this aggregate.

Comment: Hmm ...  If you want test to be default constructible, then you are allowing a and b to be omitted.